# Using a Nema 42 Stepper as a generator

Tags: power-supply

I have a Nema 42 Stepper in a wind turbine that I built.

When the turbine blades rotate from 9 rpms to say, 1200 rpms the output frequency increases.

I've converted the output from AC to DC but I don't have an oscilloscope to see how much ac ripple is present in my DC output.

I found a 200 V 4700 uF electrolytic capacitor that I want to use for dc filtering in the final output stage of my DCvoltage.

Do you guys think that this capacitor will work across my different frequency ranges?

Comment: IMarcus: Can you tell us about your rectifier, DC conversion, and load?

Comment: @Posipiet I'm not the poster, just the editor :)

Comment: You have revealed nothing about your LOAD which is a critical part of this equation.  It is also not clear WHY ripple is important at all in a "generator". Because the larger view of your "system" is not in evidence here.  Stepper motors are not as good for wind generation as ordinary DC motors because they have a lot of magnetic "impedance" and require a pretty stiff wind (and/or big blades) to be effective.

Answer (score 0):

It will work of course, but you have to understand what happens. If you have no load, you will see a nice DC voltage on your cap. If you have load' you will have ripple. If your rotation speed is low, it's not just lower frequency, but also lower voltage and much more significant ripple (and less power!). So in any case this rectified output should be further converted to DC before you connect your load or an inverter.